# Add more values

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.starRating = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        onClickCallBack: null,
    };

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var onClickCallBack = settings.onClickCallBack;

    $(".rating-star span").hover(function() {
        var hoverValue = parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'));
        highlightStars(hoverValue, 'hover');
    });

    $(".rating-star span").mouseout(function() {
        $(".rating-star span").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
    });
    $(".rating-star span").click(function() {
        if (onClickCallBack != null) {
            var rate = parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'));
            var id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'));
            highlightStars(rate, 'clicked');
            onClickCallBack(rate, id);
        }
    });

    function highlightStars(count, cssClass) {
        var itemValue = 0;
        $(".rating-star span").each(function() {
            itemValue = parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'));
            if (itemValue <= count) {
                $(this).addClass(cssClass);
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass(cssClass);
            }
        });
    }

    function highlightRating(rate) {
        var roundedRate = Math.round(rate);
        highlightStars(roundedRate, 'clicked');
    }
    return {
        highlightRatingStars: function(rate) {
            highlightRating(rate);
        }
    }

}

$(function() {
    var starRatingFunction = $.starRating({
        onClickCallBack: onRatingStar
    });

    function onRatingStar(rate, id) {
        $("#1_star_input").val(rate);
        $("#2_star_input").val(rate);
        $("#3_star_input").val(rate);
        loadData();
    }
});
```

Hi guys, I have some star rating jquery code, right now I can use one set of stars and retrieve the values but, I want to be able to get values for three different sets of stars. i'm only getting values for #1_star_input and it does the same for the other two.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question. To make the plugin work for multiple instances you need to loop through each element in the jQuery object the plugin was instantiated on

Comment: Could you make sample code on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: @vicnoob Hi, i've just thrown up some code on codepen https://codepen.io/winterlion/pen/qBObwyN

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've included a link here with my html https://codepen.io/winterlion/pen/qBObwyN